# React Native UI not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface

I am mapping an array. in table. I create table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly. as showin in image[image]

here is my code of table

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
<View style={{ flexDirection: "column", width: width / 3.1 }}>
<View
  style={{
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#C0C3C3",
    elevation: 5,
    marginTop: "2%",
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>Date</Text>
</View>
{mediDataP.map((item, i) => (
                    <View
                      key={i}
                      style={{
                        height: 50,
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        backgroundColor: "#EEF1F1",
                        elevation: 5,
                        marginTop: "2%",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>{item.date}</Text>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>





                <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", width: width / 3.9 }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      height: 50,
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      backgroundColor: "#C0C3C3",
                      elevation: 5,
                      marginTop: "2%",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>Time</Text>
                  </View>

                  {mediDataP.map((item, i) => (
                    <View
                      key={i}
                      style={{
                     
                        height: 50,
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        backgroundColor: "#EEF1F1",
                        elevation: 5,
                        marginTop: "2%",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>{item.time}</Text>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>

                </ScrollView>
```

please ignore it = I am mapping an array. in table. I am table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly. I am mapping an array. in table. I am table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly. I am mapping an array. in table. I am table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly. I am mapping an array. in table. I am table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly. I am mapping an array. in table. I am table just using view and text. but now when there is lots of value. then that UI is not showing properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the real behavior behind but i just found that on using % value of marginTop, it's has an effect depending of your component width, like with the compent which have your item.time for example; if you increase the size of the width, the size that the "2%" take increase too.